# Change cpanminus build directory

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

How can I change the [cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) default build and download directory? Its default location is `~/.cpanm` .

I already know how to change this in cpan, but I wish to know if this can also be configured in cpanminus.

I should also mention that I don't have root access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation states](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Zero-conf-How-does-this-module-get-parse-update-the-CPAN-index):

> Fetched files are unpacked in `~/.cpanm` and automatically cleaned up periodically. You can configure the location of this with the `PERL_CPANM_HOME` environment variable.

Whether you have root access is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you get "No space left to device"

rm -rf /root/.cpan/build

ln -s /somewhere/with/space /root/.cpan/build

proceed as usual